# Locomotive CMS: Dynamically Target content_types with Liquid Variable

Tags: liquid, locomotivecms

I'm building a custom navigation snippet in Locomotive CMS and I want content_type entries to be listed in the navigation along with pages.

Specifically (and obviously) I only want entries listed if the content_type has a [content_type_template](https://doc.locomotivecms.com/docs/use-them-in-templates) set up.

My plan was to set a handle (refereneced [here](https://doc.locomotivecms.com/docs/tags#path_to) but ultimately missing from the documentation) on the content_type_template page and then run the following logic when iterating through pages:

```
{% assign myContentType = loopPage.handle %}

{% for item in contents.myContentType %}

    <li>a href="{{ item._slug }}">{{ item.name }}</a></li>

{% endfor %}
```

But I've run into a problem: It seems I can't use a variable in this way. I assume there's some kind of issue with trying to plug a variable with a string value in place of a content_type slug. I wouldn't have thought it would be a problem, but it doesn't work.

I also tried:

```
{% for item in contents[myContentType] %}
```

and just to be sure:

```
{% for item in contents[myContentType].items %}
```

No joy.

**How can I dynamically target content_types in Locomotive CMS using a Liquid variable?**

Answer (score 0):

**Apparently you can't use a Liquid Variable to dynamically target content_types in Locomotive CMS.** Specifically, this won't work:

```
{% assign myVariable = some_string_that_is_the_same_as_a_content_type_slug %}

{% for item in contents.myVariable %}
```

I tried a number of methods and came to the conclusion that either:

- Liquid syntax simply doesn't accept a varibale in this context, or
- the Locomotive CMS implementation of Liquid doesn't facilitate it.

(I'd welcome confirmation or clarification on this point as I'm drawing on anecdotal evidence, not documentation.)

In the end, however, **I was able to access content_type entries dynamically using the Locomotive CMS RESTful API**. This is largely undocumented and a completely separate topic - one which warranted its own Q & A, which I have created [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64743996/locomotive-cms-access-content-type-entries-via-api).

Below is the code I used to dynmically access content_type entries. (For brevity I have included only this snippet which sits inside a number of Liquid loops to build the menu items and sub items.)

```
{% assign myContentType = loopPage.handle %}

{% action "get content_type entries" %}
    var contentData = false;
    contentData = callAPI('GET', 'https://station.locomotive.works/locomotive/api/v3/content_types/{{ myContentType }}/entries.json', {
        data: {
        },
        headers: {
            'X-Locomotive-Account-Email': '[my-account-email-adddress]',
            'X-Locomotive-Site-Handle': '[my-site-handle]',
            'X-Locomotive-Account-Token': '[my-account-token]'
        }
    });
    setProp('contentData', contentData);
{% endaction %}

{% for item in contentData.data %}

    <li><a href="{{ item._slug}}">{{ item.name }}</a></li>

{% endfor %}
```