# Locomotive CMS: Access content_type Entries via API

Tags: liquid, locomotivecms

**How can I access content_type entries via Locomotive CMS RESTful API?** I can find only [limited documentation](https://doc.locomotivecms.com/docs/upgrade-to-v3#locomotive-rest-api).

I've managed to get my auth token using the following:

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: Application/json' -d '{"email":"your@email.abc", "password":"foo"}' 'https://your.locomotive.instance.tld/locomotive/api/v3/tokens.json'
```

But now I want to access my content_entries and display their data on a page.

### Background

I'm building a custom navigation snippet in Locomotive CMS and I want content_type entries to be listed in the navigation along with pages.

Specifically (and obviously) I only want entries listed if the content_type has a content_type_template set up.

I initially thought that I could simply loop through through my pages, locate any with the slug `content_type_template`, grab the handle of that page and set it as a variable and then use the variable to get the entries like so:

```
{% for loopPage in page.children %}

    {% assign myContentType = '' %}

    {% if page.slug == 'content_type_template' %}

        {% assign myContentType = loopPage.handle %}

        {% for item in contents.myContentType %}

            <li>a href="{{ item._slug }}">{{ item.name }}</a></li>

        {% endfor %}

    {% else %}

        <li><a href="{% path_to loopPage %}">{{ loopPage.title }}</a></li>

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

But this doesn't work. As per my StackOverflow Q & A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64743076/locomotive-cms-dynamically-target-content-types-with-liquid-variable), it seems it isn't possible to use a Liquid varibale in this way.

Hence the need to access content_type entries via some other method, e.g. the Locomotive CMS REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Access content_type entries via the Locomotive CMS RESTful API as follows:

```
{% action "get content_type entries" %}
    var contentData = false;
    contentData = callAPI('GET', 'https://station.locomotive.works/locomotive/api/v3/content_types/[content_type slug]/entries.json', {
        data: {
        },
        headers: {
            'X-Locomotive-Account-Email': '[my-account-email-adddress]',
            'X-Locomotive-Site-Handle': '[my-site-handle]',
            'X-Locomotive-Account-Token': '[my-account-token]'
        }
    });

    setProp('contentData', contentData);

{% endaction %}
```

`[content_type slug]` can be replaced with a Liquid varible without any issues.